# Composite Transformation Matrix that Transforms 2D Circle

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have asked a somewhat similar question, but I am super excited to learn and use my knowledge so the problem is I cant check with anyone if I am on the right path so I will try my best to explain my question.

I have this image that has a circle that is supposed to scale down and move from it original place and the problem is I dont know if my way of thinking is correct so I will lay it down.
[image]

I am trying to create a composite transformation matrix $M$. Now my thought process is that I first scale down the circle and then move it.

$$S =\begin{bmatrix}
(4r)/6  &0  &0  \\ 
0  &(4r)/6  &0  \\ 
0  &0  &1  \\   
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$d =\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  &(x1-x0)  \\ 
0  &1 &(y1-y0)  \\ 
0  &0  &1  \\   
\end{bmatrix}$$

I dont know if this is the right approach as some of the stuff that I have watched/read said that I should first move the figure to $(0,0)$ and then scale it down and then again move it to the desired location. If I am completely messing this up I am down to rethink my method based on the feedback and thanks again for reading this.

**Edit:**
What I have tried so far I am still unsure about it

$$d_0 =\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  &(-x_0)  \\ 
0  &1 &(-y_0)  \\ 
0  &0  &1  \\   
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$S =\begin{bmatrix}
2r/3 &0  &0  \\ 
0  &2r/3 &0  \\ 
0  &0  &1  \\   
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$d_1 =\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  &(x_1)  \\ 
0  &1 &(y_1)  \\ 
0  &0  &1  \\   
\end{bmatrix}$$

so I moved the circle to origin and then scaled $r$ and lastly moved the circle to the right position. Multiplied all the three transformations like this: $d_0 * S * d_1$. I am still unsure if this is the right answer

$$M =\begin{bmatrix}
2*r/3 &0  &(-3*x_0+2*r*x_1)/3)  \\ 
0  &2*r/3 &(-3*y_0+2*r*y_1)/3)  \\ 
0  &0  &1  \\   
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to translate by $(x_1 - x_0, y_1 - y_0)$, which corresponds to the transformation

$D \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && x_1 - x_0 \\ 0 && 1 && y_1 - y_0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Then you dilate the point $(x,y)$ about $(x_1, y_1)$ by a factor $\alpha$, the new coordinates become

$x' = x_1 + \alpha (x - x_1)$

$y' = y_1 + \alpha(y - y_1) $

The corresponding transformation is

$ S = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha && 0 && (1 - \alpha) x_1 \\ 0 && \alpha && (1 - \alpha) y_1 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

The overall matrix is

$ T = S D = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha && 0 && (1 - \alpha) x_1 \\ 0 && \alpha && (1 - \alpha) y_1 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && x_1 - x_0 \\ 0 && 1 && y_1 - y_0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

This evaluates to

$ T = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha && 0 && x_1 - \alpha x_0 \\ 0 && \alpha && y_1 - \alpha y_0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

With $\alpha = \dfrac{2}{3} $ , we get

$T =  \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{2}{3} && 0 && x_1 - \dfrac{2}{3} x_0 \\ 0 && \dfrac{2}{3} && y_1 - \dfrac{2}{3} y_0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Comment: Where is this follow up question?  Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: It is the same question, but now assuming that the " circles where two generic circles". I take it that the answer would instead be `a = r1/r0`. Which in this picture is `2/4`, right ?

Comment: Why 2/4, why not 2/3 ?

Comment: oh sorry it was a typo yes I meant `2/3`

Comment: Yes, in this case, then it is correct.